# What does "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)" mean

Tags: python, exit-code, vgg-net

I am trying to run a VGG python code via PyCharm. When I run the code, I am getting:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

and I do not know what to do because it should show the 50 epochs that I am trying to execute. I have looked up the exit code and it says:

```
0xC0000409 means stack buffer overflow
```

and I don't know what that means. I am new to python code, so please explain it simple as can be lol

Comment: I would guess it's because some variable(s) in the code (likely lists or dictionaries) grew to be too large.

Comment: _Typically_, that shouldn't be able to happen in a "safe language" like Python, unless you're using native libraries written in C.

Comment: Either way, to give you a firm answer about how it happened, we need a [mre] -- the shortest possible code we can run ourselves, without changes, to see the problem and test proposed solutions. The message itself is one that can happen in too many ways to have a usefully narrow and specific answer otherwise.

Comment: BTW, this isn't _at all_ a Python-specific error. You can have a stack overflow in any language that has a call stack... all the way down to most ABIs for software written directly in assembly or machine language; hence it being something general enough to have a major programming website named after the class of problem. :)

Comment: Typically, this means some module wrote beyond the end of a buffer and trashed the stack.  As others have said, this can only happen if you are using C-based modules like `numpy` and you have violated their rules.  Are you, perhaps, trying to use a model that is way beyond the capacity of memory?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I have the code, but it is linked to a folder of images that I am testing.

Comment: @TimRoberts - IDK, I am using a Ryzen 7 with GEFORCE RTX 3080. The specific code was not running on my laptop which had Ryzen 7 with AMD Radeon. Radeon doesn't like CUDA/CUDNN as much, which is why I switched GPU.

Comment: So, if you were to try to collect information to debug this, the place to start is to attach a debugger to your Python interpreter so you can get a stack trace showing where inside the interpreter the problem is. (I don't know if the Windows builds of Python ship with debug symbols -- you might need a different copy to get full debugging functionality). That said, there's a very good chance it'll be not inside the interpreter itself, but inside a C module or library that it loaded (or a library that a C module loaded), and you'll be able to tell _that_ without needing debug symbols.